# VHD doesn't always boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot-to-vhd

I have a vhd with Windows 8 installed on it and it appears that the only way for it to boot from the vhd is to at a minimum boot into the windows 7 login screen and shut down completley from there, then once turned on it boots from the vhd. However rebooting from within Windows 8 causes a vhd initialization error, and attempting to boot right to Windows 8 also  a uses the initialization error. What could be causing this issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the VHD is not considered a bootable device from BIOS, its really software driven by the running windows OS. With out a windows session active that VHD wouldn't particularly have a means to fire up if I am understanding the situation noted.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly then the reason why the vhd will boot when Windows 7 has loaded is because the vhd gets initialized when Windows 7 loads, but it won't be initialized if the computer turns on from being off because no windows session has initialized it?

Comment: right, the VHD is not hardware driven its software driven, that being the windows OS creating space on the existing partition and emulating the driver for the disk. With out that occurring the VHD is simply a file like a PDF on the hard drive.

Comment: I think ssaviers is not completely right. See explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

BIOS firmware or UEFI firmware boot only Windows boot manager (directly or via boot records MBR+PBR).
**Firmware does not boot the OS (kernel/drivers) !**

It is Windows boot manager which starts Windows OS loader which loads kernel and drivers and gives control to kernel after loading all modules.

A VHD is a disk for Windows boot manager.

So Windows boot manager can load a Windows OS image from VHD.

To make a VHD natively bootable do this (for BIOS booting):

A) start with blank disk, initialize disk, create single partition and format it with NTFS

B) make partition active

C) place VHD on partition

D) create boot files on disk/partition

UEFI booting is different as it needs a separate EFI System Partition for boot files (+ MS Reserved Partition for Windows)